# How to download all videos frome a youtube channel whose name contains a string?

Tags: youtube-dl

I know about `youtube-dl` but I'm looking to download all the videos from a channel whose name contains a given string. Is there a way to do that, I guess one would have to extract all the videos of interest URLs with running a regex script on the HTML code of the youtube page and feed it to youtube-dl with `xargs`. Any idea how to do that more specifically ?

Comment: This is of questionable legality.  Just by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option for `youtube-dl` to do what you're looking for, it is the`--match-title REGEX` operand